# How to find a performance bottleneck in a Spring-Based Web Application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jmeter

I wrote a [performance test](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1961gOR5ihRsRKOD6sBahwG2aaeB75DUMhLSdYqtEfPU/edit?usp=sharing) using JMeter intended to measure the speed of loading a home page. The website is built using Spring MVC. The average speed is 8462 ms and the median is 8271 ms, which are pretty good. I would like to determine what component in the application that consume the most time to load the home page. What is the best technique to do this ?

Comment: Units?  44 milliseconds on average?

Comment: @duffymo they are in miliseconds

Comment: Hey, those values changed quite a lot in the past 44 minutes.  44 ms average versus 8462 ms?  20X increase?  What are you doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the server side, use Visual VM to see what's happening.  You can see heap memory, CPU, threads, and lots more.

For the client side, I'd recommend using YSlow and Chrome developer tools.  You'll be able to see each element on the page and its load time.

Comment: Thank you. I experimented with Visual VM. It is a good tool and quite easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

I think the right anwser would be to go with spring AOP.
Here a link to a strong article that explain how to do it.
http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/3763

If you have performance requirement in your application, I would suggest that you let some of those indicators in production.

Answer (score 0):

Try JVM Monitor http://www.jvmmonitor.org/. If you are using eclipse as an IDE, it's got an eclipse plugin. I found it easy to install and use. It helped me identify bottlenecks in a web application I was working on.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question is a few years old I recommend using AI tools like Digma.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion) also, please show how to use it to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: @starball no affiliation. I used the product in a project weeks ago. Once I’ve some time I‘ll update the answer with some valuable links.